# Django User model email field: how to make it mandatory

Tags: django, model

I need to make the email field in the Django User model mandatory.  It isn't obvious to me how to do that.  Suggestions welcome.  I am currently using:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
```

for my User creation form, and combining this with my own custom `UserProfileCreateForm`

Ian

Comment: You should accept his answer.

Answer (score 22):

You should be able subclass the provided registration form and override properties of a field in the `Meta` class.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# Not sure about the syntax on this one. Can't find the documentation.
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        email = {
            'required': True
        }


# This will definitely work
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['email'].required = True
```

Comment: First solution did not work for me.
The Second solution worked perfectly.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it possible to do it on the model directly ?

Answer (score 7):

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class MyUserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    email = forms.CharField(max_length=75, required=True)

    class Meta:

        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it on the model directly ?

Answer (score 0):

use `EmailField` in your model

see more at 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#emailfield