# django admin auth.User make email required

Tags: python, django

I have a quick question,

In the admin panel, you can set the user's email as unique via:

`User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True`

And I was wondering if you could also make it required like the above snippet, enforcing it through the database if so, how do I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493096/django-user-model-email-field-how-to-make-it-mandatory

Comment: @UNOwen How does it helps if you don't use a form?

Comment: @Gocht, ah, fair point, sorry I missed that.

Comment: I have a question the Django [User model email field: how to make it mandatory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493096/django-user-model-email-field-how-to-make-it-mandatory) the first answer, where does this go?

Comment: You should use that code in your form, when you use a FormView

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are asking specifically for the admin login, but assuming you are ok logging in with the regular django-allauth flow, all you need to do is add the following settings (settings.py):

```
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD= 'email'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True   
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
```

If you want to switch to using the email itself for logging in (in which case, this will also make it required, and work on the admin login as well, add also

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Your app's `settings.py`

Comment: Clarify answer that this is on the settings.py as Alex said

Comment: If what I understood is correct, I'll place this anywhere in my `settings.py` file. if that's the case then nothing happened, I can still leave the email blank

Comment: What was not clear from your question (and a disclaimer in my answer) is if you are using the django-allauth, or the django admin login. Can you clarify that? Are you logging in using /admin/login? or something like /account/login? One is managed by django, and one by allauth.