# How to make UserCreationForm email field required

Tags: django, django-forms

I am a newbie in Django.
I would like the email field in the subclassed UserCreationForm to be required.
I have tried the commented methods but none has worked so far. I have tried the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493096/django-user-model-email-field-how-to-make-it-mandatory#) but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    captcha = NoReCaptchaField()
    #email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'mdl-textfield__input'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        #email = {
        #   'required': True
        #}
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'mdl-textfield__input'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'mdl-textfield__input'}),
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'mdl-textfield__input'}),
            #'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'mdl-textfield__input'})
        }

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data["last_name"]
        user.username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        #user.user_level = self.cleaned_data["user_level"]
        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'mdl-textfield__input'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'mdl-textfield__input'
        #self.fields['email'].required=True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved the problem: `email = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'validate',}))`

Answer (score 1):

I checked Django's `User` model and it has `required=False`. So, I think you cannot achieve what you are looking for with the default User model based on [note section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) of "Overriding the default fields" in the django documentation. I have inluded the snippet

> ModelForm is a regular Form which can automatically generate certain
>   fields. The fields that are automatically generated depend on the
>   content of the Meta class and on which fields have already been
>   defined declaratively. Basically, ModelForm will only generate fields
>   that are missing from the form, or in other words, fields that weren’t
>   defined declaratively.
>
> Fields defined declaratively are left as-is, therefore any
>   customizations made to Meta attributes such as widgets, labels,
>   help_texts, or error_messages are ignored; these only apply to fields
>   that are generated automatically.
>
> Similarly, fields defined declaratively do not draw their attributes
>   like max_length or required from the corresponding model. If you want
>   to maintain the behavior specified in the model, you must set the
>   relevant arguments explicitly when declaring the form field.
>
> For example, if the Article model looks like this:
>
> ```
> class Article(models.Model):
>     headline = models.CharField(
>     max_length=200,
>     null=True,
>     blank=True,
>     help_text='Use puns liberally',
> )
> content = models.TextField() and you want to do some custom validation for headline, while keeping the blank and help_text values
> ```
>
> as specified, you might define ArticleForm like this:
>
> ```
> class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
>     headline = MyFormField(
>     max_length=200,
>     required=False,
>     help_text='Use puns liberally',
> )
>
> class Meta:
>     model = Article
>     fields = ['headline', 'content'] You must ensure that the type of the form field can be used to set the contents of the corresponding
> ```
>
> model field. When they are not compatible, you will get a ValueError
>   as no implicit conversion takes place.

So try this,

```
from django.forms import EmailField
from django.core.validators import EMPTY_VALUES

# I used django [emailfield code][2] as reference for the code of MyEmailField
# Also, following comment in django [custom form fields document][2]:
# If the built-in Field classes don’t meet your needs, you can easily create custom Field classes. To do this, just create a subclass of django.forms.Field. Its only requirements are that it implement a clean() method and that its __init__() method accept the core arguments mentioned above (required, label, initial, widget, help_text).
# You can also customize how a field will be accessed by overriding get_bound_field().

class MyEmailField(forms.EmailField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyEmailField, self).__init__(*args, strip=True, **kwargs)

    # Clean would be called when checking is_clean
    def clean(self,value):
        if value in EMPTY_VALUES:
            raise Exception('Email required')
        value = self.value.strip()
        return super(MyEmailField, self).clean(value)

class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    captcha = NoReCaptchaField()
    # All available arguments listed in django [core fields argument document][2]. Currently they are required, label, label_suffix, initial, widget, help_text, error_messages, validators, localize, disabled
    email = MyEmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        # other part of your code
```

PS: I have not tested this code but based on the documentation I think this should take you in a good direction.

Few more references:
[Django auth.user with unique email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773970/django-auth-user-with-unique-email)
[How to make email field unique in model User from contrib.auth in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160030/how-to-make-email-field-unique-in-model-user-from-contrib-auth-in-django)
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your forms.py file:

```python
class Userform(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    class meta:
         model = User
         fields = ('name','email')
```