# How to manually send a reset-password email?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-csrf

I need to manually send a password reset email upen creating a new user. I followed the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845846/django-allauth-how-to-manually-send-a-reset-password-email) and created a drive-by HttpRequest (`pwreset_request = HttpRequest()`) to do so, but all I get in return to calling `PasswordResetView.as_view()(pwreset_request)` is a 403 because of an invalid CSRF token.

Despite that (and consequently getting that email) there are no errors on the page and everything is working fine.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden, HttpResponse, HttpRequest
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token

@login_required
@permission_required(["abonnenten.verlag_sachbearbeiter_fullaccess"])
def sachbearbeiter_create_or_edit(request, username=None):
    mode = "create" if username is None else "edit"

    if mode == "create":
        user = None
        sachbearbeiter = None
    else:
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        sachbearbeiter = user.sachbearbeiter

        if user.is_superuser or user.is_staff:
            raise PermissionDenied

    user_form = UserForm(request.POST or None, instance=user)
    sachbearbeiter_form = SachbearbeiterForm(request.POST or None, instance=sachbearbeiter)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if mode == "create":
            if user_form.is_valid() and sachbearbeiter_form.is_valid():
                user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                user.email = user.username
                user.save()
                sachbearbeiter = sachbearbeiter_form.save(commit=False)
                sachbearbeiter.user = user
                sachbearbeiter.save()

                # Manually send password reset mail
                # TODO Fix this shit (403)
                pwreset_request = HttpRequest()
                pwreset_request.method = 'POST'
                pwreset_request.META['HTTP_HOST'] = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
                pwreset_request.POST = {'email': user.email, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': get_token(HttpRequest())}
                PasswordResetView.as_view()(pwreset_request)

                messages.success(request, 'Der Datensatz wurde erfolgreich gespeichert.')
                return redirect('sachbearbeiter_edit', username=user.username)
        elif mode == "edit":
            if user_form.is_valid() and sachbearbeiter_form.is_valid():
                user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                user.email = user.username
                user.save()
                sachbearbeiter_form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Der Datensatz wurde erfolgreich gespeichert.')
                return redirect('sachbearbeiter_edit', username=user.username)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Variable `mode` must be 'create' or 'edit'")

    return render(request,
                  'sachbearbeiter/edit_or_create.html',
                  {'mode': mode,
                   'user': user,
                   'user_form': user_form,
                   'sachbearbeiter_form': sachbearbeiter_form})
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I don't think that helps anyone, but here you go.

Comment: lol what do you need the template for? This has NOTHING to do with the template and I won't flood my question with any more useless clutter.

Comment: Again, it's not a problem with the template or the view. It's a problem with the `pwreset_request = HttpRequest()` only. I already tried `get_token(HttpRequest())` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why creating by hand a new `Request` object, calling the password reset view, when you can just use the `PasswordResetForm` used by this view ?

So replace all your code below:

```
# Manually send password reset mail
# TODO Fix this shit (403)
pwreset_request = HttpRequest()
pwreset_request.method = 'POST'
pwreset_request.META['HTTP_HOST'] = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
pwreset_request.POST = {'email': user.email, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': get_token(HttpRequest())}
PasswordResetView.as_view()(pwreset_request)
```

By this code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm

reset_password_form = PasswordResetForm(data={'email': user.email})
if reset_password_form.is_valid():
     reset_password_form.save(request=request) # The save method will send the email
```

Comment: I still got an error on `reset_password_form.save()` because request was NoneType. Seems obvious since it relies on being passed a `request` instance for the site name. The fix is to pass the request as a parameter like so: `reset_password_form.save(request=request)`. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for this, I tested the code above directly in the `shell_plus`  so maybe he don't need a request here. Accepted your edit.